# SAGA_CMD.exe Bad image

Tags: qgis-3, error, saga, windows

In QGIS 3.0, 3.2 and now 3.4 I get the following error message

> saga_cmd.exe bad image C:\windows\system32\vcomp140.DLL is not
>   designed to run on Windows or contains an error.

I didn't have the issue with QGIS 2.x.

Thoughts on how to resolve?